# Editing document properties in an ogv animation

Tags: animation, properties, edit

I have produced an ogv animation (with Paraview). I would like to edit the properties of the ogv file that a viewer program can then display, such as author, title and so forth.

1. Is this possible at all after the file is ready?
2. Is anything that it is wise to do with an editor?
3. Would you suggest a Linux-compatible program that enables doing this in an uncomplicated manner?

Thanks in advance for dealing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) helped me out. Say you want to add document information to test0.ogv and produce test1.ogv, then do

```
ffmpeg -i test0.ogv -metadata title="The title" -metadata artist="The artist" -metadata comment="The comment" test1.ogv
```

I have used the metadata fields acknowledged by a viewer application. I don't know whether one can invent an own field (for example, artist does exist whereas author does not). Also, I have repeated the `-metadata` option for each field, but maybe there's a way to compress this. Further suggestions welcome.